# Powershell Convert Table To Array

Tags: powershell, splunk

I'm trying to run a query in WSUS API via Powershell that outputs computer names, needed patches, etc, and then I need to inject that into a "log" file which gets ingested into Splunk so we can make dashboards etc.

My current code is

```
    $computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
    $LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
    $updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
    $wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) |
    Select-Object $logtime,@{L=’ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}},
    @{L=’NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotApplicableCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount | Select-String Computer
```

Output comes out like this:

```
@{05-13-2016_05-12-25=; ComputerTarget=########; NeededCount=12; DownloadedCount=0; NotApplicableCount=82245; NotInstalledCount=12; InstalledCount=23; FailedCount=0}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
05-13-2016_05-12-25=; ComputerTarget=#######; NeededCount=12; DownloadedCount=0; NotApplicableCount=82245; NotInstalledCount=12; InstalledCount=23; FailedCount=0
```

If you want to try the root of the problem, I'm trying to convert a table into arrays so splunk can read it line by line but this gives a table which i'm trying to convert:

```
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) |
Select-Object $logtime,@{L=’ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}},
@{L=’NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotApplicableCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount `
```

which gives output:

```
05-13-2016_05-16-04 : 
ComputerTarget      : ########
NeededCount         : 12
DownloadedCount     : 0
NotApplicableCount  : 82245
NotInstalledCount   : 12
InstalledCount      : 23
FailedCount         : 0
```

Comment: so all you need to do is to remove the `@{` and `}` of your first example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only want to remove the leading `@{` and trailing `}` which you could do with regex like this:

```
...allyourcode... | Select-String Computer | ForEach-Object { $_.Line -replace '^\@\{(.*?)\}$', '$1' }
```

However, making `Select-String` convert your objects to string-representations is a bad way to export data. Splunk can read CSV-files, so I would recommend using that (and also use a real property for logtime). Ex:

```
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) |
Select-Object @{L="LogTime";e={ $logtime }},@{L=’ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}},
@{L=’NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotApplicableCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount |
Export-Csv -Path mydata.csv -NoTypeInformation
```